# how to manipulate a mysql column field on insert?

Tags: mysql

In Persian (it's better to say Farsi), a decimal number like 32.98 is written 32/98 (slash is used instead of point)

For Example I have a table X and column L(varchar 20). I want to define a MySQL function that replaces any `/` with. In case of inserting any value to L, values are replaced before saving.

For sure it can be achieved in executed query, but I want to do it in MySQL.

Comment: what is the datatype of the column?

Comment: datatype is varchar 20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `REPLACE()`

```
SELECT L AS origL, REPLACE(L, '/', '.') AS newL
```

So in your `INSERT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO X (L) VALUES(REPLACE('yourValueHere', '/', '.'))
```

**UPDATE 1**

using `Trigger`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER replaceToPeriod
BEFORE INSERT ON X
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.L = REPLACE(NEW.L, '/', '.');
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

After the `TRIGGER` has been executed, you can now directly insert a record and the trigger replaces the value automatically.

```
INSERT INTO X (L) VALUES('32/97')
```

**UPDATE 2**

using `STORED PROCEDURE`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRecord(IN _val VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO X (L) VALUES(REPLACE(_val, '/', '.'));
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

calling the procedure:

```
CALL InsertRecord('32/97');
```

Comment: it's ok, but I do not wanna execute any query. I want to define something like a procedure

Comment: I think you are looking for `TRIGGER`. Please wait.